# Adapting Windows project to Linux System

Tags: windows, linux-device-driver

I'm currently having to adapt a project written in C for a Windows System (and a MinGW Compiler) to a Linux System. 
I have read about Cross Compilation but it doesn't seem to be helpful enough for my case, since I'm working with a 64-bits Windows Machine whereas my Linux system is a 32-bits. 
Plus, I've got a whole lot of DLL calls in my project and since these DLLs don't necessarily exist on Linux, it will cause trouble.
I wonder if anyone in the StackOverlfow comunity knows how I can solve (or at least ease) my problem. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: You'll have to go through **a lot** of **refactoring**. Cross platform applications must be written with this in mind from the **very beginning** (otherwise you'll be able to reuse only very little code). If you didn't...well there is not so much you can do now, **be patient** and **rewrite to isolate system specific code** in separate libraries/modules (which you can simply rewrite for each system). Use a **cross platform library** for everything you can (for example QT for interface, boost for many many other things and so on).

Comment: Oh, I saw just now that you tagged your question with **linux-device-driver**. If you have to rewrite a **device driver** then **forget** to port most of your code, almost everything is different at this level (only things you may save are _algorithms_ but usually they're so tied with specific system calls that you can't extract them and there you wouldn't pay the performance hit of abstractions).

Comment: This is way too broad. Clearly you'll need to modify your code, but only you can work out what needs to be done.

Comment: "If you have to rewrite a device driver" @Adriano Yes Actually, it's a whole Driver Kit which is designed for a Windows-based system with a MinGW compiler, and that I have to port to a Linux/Debian... I have actually started looking at the code, adapting some little things, but I still get a lot of errors :( I feel it's gonna take me a little while to make this work :-s

Comment: In order to get a more concrete answer than "it's **really** difficult", you will have to post some example code to show how entangled with Windows your code is.

Comment: I wouldn't even start. Even (little portions of) code may compile (because no system calls) may be a big source of problems because **architecture** is too different. Applications are portable (with exceptions, libraries and a lot of extra work). Drivers are not (very often even between different version of the same OS, imagine from Windows to Linux). Let's write it from beginning, you'll need less time (this is just a guess because I don't see your code but...)

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to port a Windows device driver to Linux, you may as well throw out the code. The Linux kernel works very differently to the Windows kernel. Since you have basically no abstraction in kernel programming, there is no real way to make cross-platform drivers, even if you use a Linux toolchain on Windows.

Linux and Windows have completely different kernel designs, meaning the code you write for one simply won't work on the other. It is difficult enough to try and compile Linux userspace programs on Windows, let alone trying to entirely port Windows drivers to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for you answers. Actually, I think as well that this is practically impossible de adapt the code (what's more, it's not even one appliction only, but several .c and .h files for a specific driver of a specific electronic board...). I have therefore started to test the code on a Windows OS for the moment, and then I'll see what I'm going to do with my Linux system...